# How do I display MySQL table data in a row and column

Tags: php, mysql, html

```html
<?php

mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'Pass');
mysql_select_db('add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

echo "$row[url]";
}

?>
```

I have used this code to display url on a webpage.it display like 
http:\12122.comhttp:\asfasfasfas.com   and so on .
i want to display this url with some gap like this

```
      http:\\12122.com           http:\\asfasfasfas.com 
      http:\\fgsdgsg.com         http:\\fdgfdagfgf.com
```

Comment: PLEASE UPVOTE MY QUESTION I AM NOT ABLE TO ASK NEW

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display MySQL table data in a row and column and link it to an external webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252289/how-do-i-display-mysql-table-data-in-a-row-and-column-and-link-it-to-an-external)

Comment: Why are you using backslashes in your URL protocols? They should be  forward slashes (`http://`).

Comment: Is the user whose answer you have accepted a duplicate account under your control? It is expected here that people only have one account each, to reduce voting fraud.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should try

```html
<?php

mysql_connect('servername', 'username', 'Password');
mysql_select_db('add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

echo '<div style="min-width:180px;height:40px;border:gray 1px;float:left;">'.$row['url']. '</div>';
}

?>
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

quick solution is:

```
$left_right = 'left'
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
if ($left_right == 'left' ) {
    echo $row['url'];
    $left_right = 'right';
} else {
    echo '     yuor gap    '.$row['url']."\n";
    $left_right = 'left';
} 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php

mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'Pass');
mysql_select_db('add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

echo '<div style="min-width:180px;height:40px;border:gray 1px;float:left;">'.$row['url']. '</div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the modulus of the loop and accordingly place the output left and right with the help of CSS.

```
$i=0;
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
    {
    if ($i % 2 == 0 ) {
        echo '<div style="float:right">$row[url]</div>;
    } else {
        echo '<div style="float:left">$row[url]</div>;
    } 
$i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each url in a span tag and set its css margin to push them apart, try this:

```
<?php
echo '<span style="margin:20px;float:left;">http://site1.com</span>';
echo '<span style="margin:20px;float:left;">http://site2.com</span>';
echo '<span style="margin:20px;float:left;">http://site3.com</span>';
echo '<span style="margin:20px;float:left;">http://site4.com</span>';
?>
```

So, in the while loop, do this:

```
echo '<span style="margin:20px;float:left;">$row[url]</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<?php

mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'Pass');
mysql_select_db('add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage');

$i = 1;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
    echo "<div style='float:left; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px'>".$row['url']."</div>";

    if($i % 2 == 0)
    {
        echo "<div style='clear:both'></div>";
    }

    $i++;
}

?>
```